# Echo array from sql in php program

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to get all the `post IDs` from `yesterday` on wordpress, the SQL query works well when I tried it on `phpMyAdmin`, it returns all `IDs` from yesterday. However when I tried to echo the `IDs` out of the array, the values in the array is '`Array`' instead of the `ID`, which should be numbers. I wonder why did the `IDs` in the array all turned into the word 'Array'. This is the code I wrote:

```
$yesterday = strtotime("-1 days");
$day = (int)date("d", $yesterday);
$month = (int)date("n", $yesterday);
$year = (int)date("Y", $yesterday);

$sql = "
    SELECT ID
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND DAY(post_date) = $day
    AND MONTH(post_date) = $month
    AND YEAR(post_date) = $year
";

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_N');

foreach ($results as $id) {
    echo '<br>' . $id;
}
```

Update:
I changed the type of output to `ARRAY_A` and added the `var_dump()` before the `foreach` loop to see what's inside the array, and this is what I got:

[image: output]

Comment: wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )
Return #
(array|object|null) Database query results
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ARRAY_A` to get associative array instead of `ARRAY_N` which returns numerically indexed multidimensional array .. `$results` in your code is multidimensional array .. 
use `var_dump()` instead on echo to view variable contents ( for testing )

Comment: `echo $id['ID'];`

Comment: with the `var_dump()` I can see that the `ID`s are stored inside an array inside another larger array, I got a screen capture of the output and updated in the post. So now when I put a `foreach` loop for the inner array inside the `foreach` loop for the larger array, it prints the `ID` out, thanks for the suggestion on `var_dump()` to check.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11938822/3367442) you should do the following code in the `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo '<br>' . $result->id;
}
```

Try to print the `$results` and get the appropriate object.

Comment: I got no output with that code, and printing `$results` gives me 'Array'